# Kendo grid has changes always return false

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid in my c# project and i want to check whether have any changes been made to the item in grid. I use below code to check it but it always return false.

```
            var data = $("#field-grid").data("kendoGrid");
            var hasChanges = data.dataSource.hasChanges();
```

My grid

```
                var fieldGrid = $("#field-grid").kendoGrid({
                height: 320,
                dataSource: fieldDataSource,
                selectable: "row",
                scrollable: true,
                columns: [...],
                editable: { mode: "inline", "createAt": "bottom", confirmation: false },
                save: function (e) {
                    dataSource = $("#field-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource,
                    item = dataSource.getByUid(e.model.uid);
                    item.dirty = true; 
                }
            }).data("kendoGrid");
```

I put a break point in my grid `save` event and notice that the `hasChanges` actually become true once user made changes on the item in grid. But dont know why later it will become false again.

Comment: What is the code for the grid configuration ?

Comment: @Richard see my update..

Comment: Good to see the grid configuration, it works hand-in-hand with the data source.  What is the code for the data source configuration ?  https://dojo.telerik.com/ is really helpful for learning the Telerik framework and setting up examples for questions when you need help.  If you can prepare a 'dojo' demonstrating a problem you might see 'the answer' yourself, and likely get great answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

When you make changes to an item in the grid, the datasource gets updated and hasChanges() returns true. After those changes are saved, hasChanges() returns false. This is entirely correct since after saving, there are no longer any changes. The function effectively indicates whether there are any unsaved changes, not whether there have been changes made and saved in the past.

You are seeing a value of true in the save event function because that fires immediately before kendo carries out its own internal save processing which will set hasChanges() to false. If you want to keep track of whether changes have been made and saved, set your own variable in the save event function.